# Keeping track of a pool of workers via JMS

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, cluster-computing, load-balancing

I have an application consisting of several Java services, which communicate through direct RMI lines. I'm about to upgrade this to something more modern and stable using JMS / ActiveMQ.

- The most common scenario is a number of processes connecting to a central service and performing requests. -> This can be implemented in JMS with a named request queue and named or temporary response queues.
- Through the above link, processes will also register themselves as event listeners with the central service, which maintains a list of them, and dispatches events by sending it to each subscriber directly via RMI. -> A JMS topic is an ideal replacement for this.

The third scenario is more complex: I'll also have several processes registering themselves as workers with the central service. This central service will have to maintain a pool of those workers, which can be started, stopped and restarted dynamically and unexpectedly.

The pool will then assign tasks to specific workers (e.g. the worker with the lowest load, so no broadcasting or random selection). But I don't think that'll be very difficult, the core problem is keeping the pool up to date.

The workers will also need to communicate back with information about the running tasks or the general worker status (e.g. current load, or, is it accepting new tasks).

How might I implement this, in a stable way, on top of JMS? Well, explaining how to fully implement this complex scenario may be a bit much, but are there general design patterns that can be applied here, assuming the availability of queue- and topiclike channels?

Comment: I see that primary problem is intercommunication between services, so maybe JMS is not a best option here? How about Storm/Akka? https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Tutorial.html